# Hiding a related list on shared layout

Tags: page-layout

A client has 2 profiles separating 2 distinct sets of users. Can I add a related list to the contact object which only one profile has rights to the object such that the users in the other profile will not even see the related list when viewing a contact?

Does this work?

Thanks

Comment: Remeber to accept the answers provided by other community members, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a related list to a page layout which will then not appear to users whose profile does not grant them access to the related object.

Because permissions are enforced through multiple layers of functionality, you should test this in a sandbox to ensure that the full configuration of your organization results in the desired effect.